# REST API GROUP versioning

Tags: rest, api-versioning

Does anybody know what is Group versioning in REST API? 
I found the link below where it explains it, but i don't understand how to use it.

I am looking for:

1. How to configure group version across multiple endpoints ?
2. Can someone provide practical example of it ?

[Github Microsoft API guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#1211-group-versioning)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the vernacular, **Group** versioning is really nothing more than versioning by date. Most, if not all, Azure services version this way. You can choose whether you want to version by number or date - the two most common formats. Versioning by **Group** (e.g. date) is convenient for services. You know exactly when things were released. It can be difficult to track when a numeric version was deployed over time. Whether you map the *group* to some internal value is up to you, but I would claim it doesn't bring you anything but complexity and confusion. If you use a date for your version number, embrace it through and through.

The guidelines somewhat imply that you can have varying minor versions mapping to a single group (e.g. date); that could be dangerous. It's generally assumed that a minor version is backward compatible; however, a service should **never** assume that this is true. A service has no control over a client and their ability to handle even additive content (e.g. *tolerant reader*). The **only** type of versioning behind a group that *should* ever be done is patching, which has no visible wire protocol differences. You'll have to decide if it's worth mapping patch versions to groups/dates internally.

Whether you choose to version by number, date, or even both, is up to you. [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/) is one such realization of these guidelines. It also includes support for a *status* (ex: Beta), which no longer appears in the formal REST guidelines. The [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Version-Format) contains in-depth details.

I hope that helps.